# whatsapp sticker pack adding issue

Tags: android, whatsapp, whatsapp-stickers

I am using this demo to create custom sticker for my app.

https://github.com/idoideas/StickerMaker-for-Whatsapp

all working fine but when I try to add sticker pack, I'm getting this error.

[image]

I search a google but I can't find answer or clue.

Comment: This is beacuse there is some issue in your StickerBook class, The contents.json file is not created or either it has wrong structure.